# Why child pom-files does not extend parent pom dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, maven, microservices

I created simple microservice project with structure:

```
project/          <-- Root directory
|-- user/         <-- Submodule 1
|-- service2/     <-- Submodule 2
|-- pom.xml       <-- Root POM
```

I'm using `Lombok` and I want to avoid duplicating and not to add its dependency in every service pom. So I added it to root pom and added services like modules:

4.0.0
pom

```
<modules>
    <module>user</module>
    <module>service2</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>project</name>
<description>Micro service project</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!--Utils-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>netflix-candidates</id>
        <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
        <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

So in user service  now I have pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>user</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>user</name>
<description>user</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <!--                Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--        Security-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--        Test-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--                Database&tools-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongock-springboot-v3</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-springdata-v4-driver</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.BETA</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>

    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>netflix-candidates</id>
        <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
        <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Unfortunately lombok's annotations aren't processed in user service in such approach. Why user service does not extend `Lombok` dependency?

Comment: Why should it? It doesn't extend the parents pom but just the spring boot parent.

Comment: how to extend parent pom in this case?

Comment: Define it as the parent of your child instead of the spring boot starter parent. You are also mixing Spring BOot versions and using incompatible `hibernate-validator` so not sure what you are doing here. Next to that, when using the root as a parent you m ight want to remove the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` from the parent as not all childs probably need that plugin.

Comment: aha, added root pom as parent, it helped. I tried to use hibernate-validator to put constrints to entities. also its not clear why spring-boot-maven plugin should be removed-all my microservices are based on spring-boot

Comment: `hibernate-validator` already comes with `spring-boot-starter-validator`. The version you included is an old incompatible version and will lead to issues, remove it. The fact that something is based on spring boot doesn't mean it is a spring boot application. Only the project containing `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class should use this plugin.

Comment: got your idea. added parent to services poms and it works. yes, all services are annotated by @SpringBootApplication. could you insert comment in.answer and I will accept it?